# Functions not using variables from functions above them

Tags: python, global-variables

I have a program where I have defined a function called `historyA()`

```
def historyA(self, name, price, category, sub, comment):
    sh = login("Budget")
    worksheet = sh.get_worksheet(0)
    emptyrowresize()
    date = getDate()
    toAppend = [date, name, category, sub, price, comment]
    worksheet.append_row(toAppend)
```

In this function it is giving the variable worksheet values.

Immediately after that it runs the function `emptyrowresize()`

```
def emptyrowresize():
    print("\n")
    count = 0
    cycle = 0
    empty = False

    for i in range(emptyrowcount()):
        for i in range(worksheet.col_count):
            if(lastvalue(i+1) == ""):
                count += 1
            if(count >= worksheet.col_count):
                empty = True
            if(empty == True):
                worksheet.resize(worksheet.row_count-1,worksheet.col_count)
                print("Fixing empty row at {0}..." .format(worksheet.row_count+1))
                break
```

`emptyrowresize()` calls the functions `lastvalue()` in it

```
def lastvalue(x, y=0):
    cycles = 0
    #returns last value in col x with vertical offset y
    while(True):
        count = worksheet.row_count
        val = worksheet.cell(int(count-y), x).value
        cycles += 1
        if(val == ''):
            y = cycles
        else:
            break
    return val
```

and last value needs the worksheet that was named in `historyA()` but it keeps giving the error that worksheet is not a defined global variable.

Why is this not working? I have had a problem with this once before but I don't remember how I fixed it without making a separate function for each of the three worksheets I need to work with.

EDIT: I feel like it is worth mentioning that everything passed `historyA()` is in a separate file that I am importing. I'm not sure if that means anything.

Comment: Variables defined in a function are local to that function and can't be accessed from anywhere else (unless you mark them as global).  There are numerous other questions about this on StackOverflow, including many listed as "Related" on the right of this page.

Comment: I saw those answers but almost all of them are using the global variables on separate functions. This is different in that I am using it in functions within it and from different modules.

Comment: Plus I really don't want to have to use a global variable because it may mess with other parts of the program.

Comment: Just pass `worksheet` into `emptyrowresize` and `lastvalue`. So, define `emptyrowresize` like this: `def emptyrowresize(worksheet):` Then, in `historyA`, call it like this: `emptyrowresize(worksheet)`